# NTAG21x password works for write but not read

Tags: android, passwords, nfc

I'm using `NTAG213` and Android.

First I set the `PASSWORD` and `PACK`. Then I set AUTH0 to page 0. With `ACCESS = 0` the NFC tag is read only.

I confirm this with `NXP TagInfo`.

I can write new data to the tag after authenticating with my app. When I change ACCESS to 1 (mem page 42, byte 0 = 0x80) the tag is read/write protected.

Again checking with `TagInfo` I cannot read the tag data. After authenticating with my app, I can not read or write the data.

Any idea why my authentication does not allow me to read/write the data?

When entering the PASSWORD I get a `TagLostException`.

Comment: Could you try if the password authentication (if read/write access is protected) works if you set AUTH0 to page **6** (assuming that you leave pages 3, 4 and 5 in their delivery state)?

Comment: I can set read/write protection from page 5 and higher without problems. I use static lock bytes to read-only lock page 4 giving me a suitable workaround for my application but I would prefer to lock page 2 as well.

Comment: I understand that this is not a solution to your problem it was rather meant as a help for me to trace the problem. You are using an Android device based on the Broadcom NFC chipset, right?

Comment: Not 100% sure. I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300. From what I can find on google I think it uses NXP's PN65.

Comment: That's using NXP's NFC chipset.